# Android XML Layout Padding Error: activity_horizontal/vertical_margin

Tags: android, xml

Hi my xml android code is having an error, I have searched already and can't find any info. Im trying to set layout padding to activity horizontal/vertical margin but its all red. Please help thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:paddingRight="activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:paddingBottom="activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `activity_horizontal_margin` is not defined anywhere that's why you are getting this error.
one of the solution can be.

1. add in **App level build gradle**:

   ```
   implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
   implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
   ```
2. and then give padding like this:

   ```
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   ```

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just remove "androidx.gridlayout.widget." and use "<GridLayout" instead of "<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout"

or add this dependency for using androidx gridlayout

```
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
```

Comment: both did not work

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong , padding attributes either takes values like 4dp,8dp etc or a reference to a resource file where you store the values.

If you want to use a reference to dimensions just right click on values directory and chose New -> Value Resource File , name it dimen and hit ok

After that add these in the file :

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>   //change dimensions to your preference
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

And then change padding attributes to this :

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: the textbook I am using is from 2015, maybe its a different api/sdk? They did not do any of that

Comment: what sdk version are u using ?

Comment: can you tell me what textbook you are using ??

Comment: Android How to Program Second Edition Deitel and Harvey I am using Lollipop but this book was written for older versions. I can't find any info on the change of code anywhere...

Comment: No worries, now u know the new way, try my solution and see if it solves ur problem.

Comment: I know that you can use "16dp" for a size but I thought that would work. Anyways thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I had to use values such as 16dp (already knew this), it seems those other strings have been taken out as they are from older versions of android (can't find any info on google showing that the api has been changed even on the android.developer website).